# How to provide communicate from panel to frame in java

Tags: java, swing, interface, jpanel, cardlayout

I have used cardlayout in my main class. I have added first panel in that cardlayout. I'm trying to hide the image in frame from first panel. So I have used interface like below code,

My Main class,

```
public class HomePage implements OptionMenuListener{

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); // Already there
        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setLayout(new CardLayout(20, 20));

        File file = new File(jsonFilePath);
        if(!file.exists()) {
            LoginPage login = new LoginPage();
            contentPane.add(login, Constants.CARD_LOGIN);
            ConfigueBranch configureBranch = new ConfigueBranch(false);
            contentPane.add(configureBranch, Constants.CARD_CONFIGURE_BRANCH);
            ConfigureSystem configureSystem = new ConfigureSystem(false);
            contentPane.add(configureSystem, Constants.CARD_CONFIGURE_SYSTEM);
            ConfigureCustomer configureCustomer = new ConfigureCustomer(false);
            contentPane.add(configureCustomer, Constants.CARD_CONFIGURE_CUSTOMER);
        }
        MainPage mainPage = new MainPage(HomePage.this);
        contentPane.add(mainPage, Constants.CARD_MAINPAGE);
//      SettingsPage configureExpinContainer = new SettingsPage();
//      contentPane.add(configureExpinContainer, Constants.CARD_SETTINGS_PAGE);

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(50, 10, 10, 10));

        Image image = MyUtil.loadImage("/logo.png"); // transform it
        Image newimg = image.getScaledInstance(244, 80, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(newimg); // transform it back
        JLabel label = new JLabel("", icon, JLabel.LEFT);
        label.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 24));
        label.setOpaque(true);
        label.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        label.setBounds(0, 60, 300, 200);
        buttonPanel.add(label);
        frame.add(contentPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setSize(1000, 700);
        centeredFrame(frame);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setResizable(false);
    }

    public static void centeredFrame(javax.swing.JFrame objFrame) {
        Dimension objDimension = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        int iCoordX = (objDimension.width - objFrame.getWidth()) / 2;
        int iCoordY = (objDimension.height - objFrame.getHeight()) / 2;
        objFrame.setLocation(iCoordX, iCoordY);
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onMenuSelect(boolean isShow) {

    }
}
```

I'm using for interface to provide communication to frame from panel,

```
public interface OptionMenuListener {
    void onMenuSelect(boolean isShow);
}
```

I'm using the below panel in cardlayout,

public class MainPage extends JPanel{

```
JButton inputOutputFilesBtn, syncBtn, tsBtn, settingsBtn;
public MainPage(HomePage homePage){
    homePage.onMenuSelect(true);
    init();
}

public void init(){
    JTabbedPane jtbExample = new JTabbedPane();
    JPanel jplInnerPanel1 = createInnerPanel("No device connected");
    jtbExample.addTab("Input and Output Files", jplInnerPanel1);
    jtbExample.setSelectedIndex(0);
    JPanel jplInnerPanel2 = createInnerPanel("No device connected");
    jtbExample.addTab("Sync", jplInnerPanel2);
    JPanel jplInnerPanel3;
    if(configuredSystem.equalsIgnoreCase("Expeditors")) {
        jplInnerPanel3 = createInnerPanel("No device connected");
        jtbExample.addTab("TS", jplInnerPanel3);
    }
    JPanel jplInnerPanel4 = new SettingsPage();
    jtbExample.addTab("Settings", jplInnerPanel4);
    JPanel jplInnerPanel5 = new LogoutPage();
    jtbExample.addTab("Logout", jplInnerPanel5);
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(620, 400));
    this.add(jtbExample, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(jtbExample);

}

protected JPanel createInnerPanel(String text) {
    JPanel jplPanel = new JPanel();
    JLabel jlbDisplay = new JLabel(text);
    jlbDisplay.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    jplPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
    jplPanel.add(jlbDisplay);
    return jplPanel;
}
```

But i'm getting **Cannot use this in a static context** error in this below line

```
MainPage mainPage = new MainPage(HomePage.this);
```

Now i want to send some information from panel to the frame which have cardlayout. Could you please suggest me an idea to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you want to do ? `HomePage.this` would be the instance IF it was not in a `static` context. here, `this` doesn't exist. If you need an instance, either put that code in the constructor/method of HomePage or simply declare an instance `HomePage hp = new HomePage()` and pass that instance to the `MainPage`. For me, this is a design problem, I never put that many GUI initialisation in a static method.

Comment: Make method `createAndShowGUI` not static. to send some information from panel to the frame, create method in frame and call it from panel

Comment: @JaySmith Thanks for the response. I could not change createAndShowGUI non static because i'm using it inside public static void centeredFrame(javax.swing.JFrame objFrame) {} method

Comment: method `createAndShowGUI` is not used inside method `centeredFrame`

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `this` in a static context like since `this` represent the class instance that is executing a method. Here, you are in a static context, so you don't have an instance.

```
private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    MainPage mainPage = new MainPage(HomePage.this);
}
```

You either need to declare a variable

```
private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    HomePage homePage = /*initialize or get it from somewhere */
    MainPage mainPage = new MainPage(homePage);
}
```

Or move that logic outside the static context

```
private void createAndShowGUI() {
    MainPage mainPage = new MainPage(HomePage.this);
}
```